# chat-example in socket.io won't work in phonegap. I am keep having that error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is the error I am getting

[image: Bad request error when lunch in phongap]

```
{
"name": "com.bg.lter",
"displayName": "LTER",

"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the 
 deviceready event.",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "Apache Cordova Team",
"license": "Apache-2.0",
"dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-websocket-server": "^1.4.10",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.0",
    "socket.io-parser": "^3.2.0"

},
"cordova": {
    "plugins": {
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
        "cordova-plugin-websocket-server": {},
        "cordova-plugin-file": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
        "ios",
        "android",
        "browser"
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[![git clone https://github.com/socketio/chat-example.git is the code base for my integration in phonegap, but I am keep having this error.][1]][1]

[Here more of my code, or you can check the original from ] https://i.stack.imgur.com/d92Pv.png